# How to make bazel pick up right version of com_google_protobuf_cc repository for loaded gRPC repository?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel

I'm building a program with gRPC library using bazel. My WORKSPACE file:

```
http_archive(
    name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
    urls = ["https://github.com/grpc/grpc/archive/v1.8.3.zip"],
    sha256 = "57a2c67abe789ce9e80d49f473515c7479ae494e87dba84463b10bbd0990ad62",
    strip_prefix = "grpc-1.8.3",
)

load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")
grpc_deps()
```

BUILD file:

```
proto_library(
    name = "test_proto",
    srcs = ["test.proto"],
)

cc_proto_library(
    name = "test_cc_proto",
    deps = [":test_proto"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["hello.cc"],
    deps = [ 
        ":test_cc_proto",
        "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc++",
    ],  
)
```

Compiling this throws error:

```
every rule of type proto_library implicitly depends upon the target '@com_google_protobuf_cc//:cc_toolchain', but this target could not be found because of: no such package '@com_google_protobuf_cc//': The repository could not be resolved.
```

If I include com_google_protobuf_cc repository manually, the version doesn't match and I get error saying test.pb.h was generated using a newer version of protoc.

How do I make gRPC load right version of com_google_protobuf_cc?

Answer (score 0):

How are you including Protobuf manually, what did you put in your BUILD and/or WORKSPACE file/s to achieve this? It's hard to comment on what could be wrong without knowing exactly what you have tried.

As far as I know you can include it by downloading the version you require then adding something like the following to your WORKSPACE file:

```
local_repository(
    name = "com_google_protobuf",
    path = "../protobuf-3.4.1",
)

local_repository(
    name = "com_google_protobuf_cc",
    path = "../protobuf-3.4.1",
)
```

Of course change the paths to match the version and location of your downloaded copy of Protobuf. Alternatively you can probably use http_archive to point it directly to where it should be downloaded, in the same way as you have done for gRPC.

Comment: Workspace name in /home/chakradarraju/.cache/bazel/_bazel_chakradarraju/0549007034a1e84cfecc4d5dd5eb47c0/external/com_google_protobuf_cc/WORKSPACE (@com_google_protobuf) does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@com_google_protobuf_cc); this will cause a build error in future versions.

Comment: That seems to only be a warning, not an error, what is actually happening?